American Citizen trying to get married in Italy but running out of time
Naively, my fiancée (Italian) and I (American) thought that we could get married while I was on the 90-day tourist visa.  We've been informed that there is pretty much no chance of that.  We have our Dichiarazione Giurata (from the American Embassy) and our Atto Notorio but we're being told that the Pubblicazione and the actual marriage won't take place for a couple of MONTHS because of bureaucracy (preparing the pubblicazione, booking the hall)!  I have about 2 weeks left of the 90 days.
Is there anything I can do to stay here and get married without spending thousands traveling between Italy and the US or waiting 3 months?  The lawyer we spoke to here basically told me to overstay because Italy won't do anything unless I have a run-in with the police.  If I overstayed, would I run into trouble even though I want to stay here and I'm going to apply for residency?  Can I even apply for the residency card after overstaying?
I know my  case is like this one but there was never any update to it and I have no idea how it worked out.  Natario, if you see this, I'd love an update.

I would trust your lawyer. Protection of family rights is very strong in the EU and Italy is indeed considered fairly "lax" on the enforcement side. Or you can try getting married in places like Denmark and U.S. where the process can be very quick.
